# Drawing a simple chart using D3 and C3

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, d3.js, c3.js

I am using node.js (I am not sure if it matters in this case). I am trying to draw a simple bar chart using d3 and c3. My html looks like below. There is no output. What am I doing wrong here?

```js
var chart = c3.generate({
 data:{
  columns:[
  ['data1', 90, 30]
  ],
  type: 'bar'
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.18/c3.js"></script>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="chart"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var chart = c3.generate({
 data:{
  columns:[
    ['data1', 90, 30, 100, 200]
  ],
  type: 'bar'
 }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://rawgit.com/masayuki0812/c3/master/c3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.18/c3.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

You have to use `d3.v3` with `c3` and not the `d3.v4`...

Comment: Honestly, how is this different from mine ?

Comment: the main change is that from the v4 d3 is now modular so you haven't need to import whole its modules you can install/import modules you need. For more: https://iros.github.io/d3-v4-whats-new/#1

Answer (score 0):

Use D3 v3 not v4.

```js
  var chart = c3.generate({
 data:{
  columns:[
  ['data1', 90, 30]
  ],
  type: 'bar'
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.18/c3.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```